# JMeter - How to pass output from HTTP Sampler as input to OS Process Sampler

Tags: jmeter

I have a jmeter test plan with a pair of samplers. The first retrieves a keycloak token from an HTTP endpoint. The second is an OS Process Sampler that is supposed to take the response from the first sampler and remove the JSON artifacts from the response.

The first sampler works fine, I get the json-wrapped token returned. The second sampler is not operating on the output of the first as I had hoped. Here is the command:

```
jq .access_token -r
```

This command technically executes successfully, but there is no data in the response. I am guessing I had to somehow tell the OS Process Sampler to use the response of the HTTP sampler as input (from a curl command you would pipe the response from the HTTP call the to jq).

I would be grateful if someone knows how I get output of the first sampler as input to the second. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is really what you're looking for you can:

1. Add [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler and provide an arbitrary variable name, i.e. `response` there
2. The response of the `HTTP Request` sampler will be available as `${response}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and you will be able to use it anywhere else including OS Process Sampler

---

However be informed that JMeter comes with [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) and [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide/) so you can extract your token from the JSON response using any of them, this way you will avoid unnecessary calling of the command-line interpreter, moreover you wont' have to rely on `jq` program presence on the machine where you will be running your tests.

Comment: thanks I am now trying the JSON Extractor. Here is sample input to JOSN Extractor: {"access_token":"encryptedAccessTokenValue","expires_in":300,"refresh_expires_in":0,"token_type":"Bearer","not-before-policy":14781,"scope":"email profile"}    I added the JSON extractor to my token retreiver, and put $..access_token as the json path expression. However, when I run the test, I still see josn wrapper in the Results Tree Response Data. Am I extracting wrong or am I looking in wrong place for results? thanks

Comment: You need to provide a variable name in the "Names of created variables" input field as well, i.e. `token`. Once done you will be able to access the extracted value as `${token}` where required (my expectation is that you will need to use in in the [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)) or see the value using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/)

Comment: thanks I was able to see my token variable with Debug Sampler as per your suggestion. thanks